# Can not set specific values for the x axis in a plot plotting ogives

Tags: r, plot

I am doing a plot with two different ogives. The plot works great, y axis is correct, but the problem is the x axis.
I want the X axis to go from 0 to 18.000 by 1000. But it is not working!!

For some reason nothing is working!! The X axis changes for every plot I do. I can not set specific values!

Does anyone know what is going on? It is really weird

```
points<-ogive.freq(h,col="red",ylab="Frecuencia Relativa Acumulada",main="localidad")
j<-graph.freq(NiñoOK,plot=FALSE)
puntos<-ogive.freq(j,col="blue")

plot(puntos,type="b",xaxt="n",pch=19,las=1,bty="l",col="blue",ylab="Frecuencia Relativa Acumulada")
lines(points,col="red",type="b",pch=19,bty="l")
axis(1, at = seq(0, 18000, by = 1000), las=1)
```

I also tried this and did not work either

```
axis(1, at = seq(0, 14000, by = 2000),labels=c("0","2000","4000","6000"
                ,"8000","10000","12000","14000"), las=2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!
You have to add `xlim=c(0,14000)` in plot()

```r
points<-ogive.freq(h,col="red",ylab="Frecuencia Relativa Acumulada",main="localidad")
j<-graph.freq(NiñoOK,plot=FALSE)
puntos<-ogive.freq(j,col="blue")

plot(puntos,type="b",xaxt="n",pch=19,las=1,bty="l",col="blue",ylab="Frecuencia Relativa Acumulada")
lines(points,col="red",type="b",pch=19,bty="l")
axis(1, at = seq(0, 18000, by = 1000), las=1)
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and format it properly.